# ¿Por qué se dice "sudar la gota gorda"?

Tags: coloquialismos, locuciones

El Diccionario de la Lengua recoge [**"sudar la gota gorda"**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JN4MHke) como:

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Sudar mucho, pasar calor.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Esforzarse mucho, trabajar con fatiga o desvelo.

Supongo que  "la gota gorda" es un potenciador de sudar, pero ¿por qué precisamente **"gota gorda"**?

Comment: Curiosamente, la primera vez que se recogió la expresión fue en 1803 en el diccionario de la RAE, aunque por entonces era "sudar la gota tan gorda".

Comment: Relacionado: [en gordo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JLSh4xE) quiere decir _Con abundancia, o de forma importante_ y de hecho _gordo_ tiene acepciones que fácilmente se pueden interpretar como de abundancia genérica (no solo de grasa, vaya)

Answer (score 6):

La expresión no tiene mucho misterio, pero es interesante conocer su origen. Al igual que cuando llueve no es lo mismo una lluvia fina que una lluvia con goterones gordos (esta última suele ser de mayor intensidad), con el sudor se tiene la misma imagen.

Cuando una persona suda le empiezan a aparecer gotas de sudor, visibles sobre todo en la zona de la frente. Al igual que con la lluvia, se saca la imagen de que cuanto mayor es el tamaño de la gota, mayor es el esfuerzo.

Al principio la expresión se usaba como una comparación, y por eso en el diccionario de la RAE de 1803, la primera edición que recoge la expresión, aparece como "sudar la gota tan gorda". Se puede ver un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir en el siguiente texto (negritas mías):

> *A lo que he venido es que anoche el Renegado y Centopiés llevaron a mi casa una canasta de colar, algo mayor que la presente, llena de ropa blanca; y en Dios y en mi ánima que venía con su cernada y todo, que los pobretes no debieron de tener lugar de quitalla, y **venían sudando la gota tan gorda que era una compasión verlos entrar jadeando y corriendo agua de sus rostros**, que parecían unos angelicos.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Rinconete y Cortadillo [Novelas ejemplares]", 1613 (España).

Hay un par de casos más antiguos, del siglo XVI, como el siguiente:

> *Si estar en la plaza ociosos en negocio tan reprehensible, ¿qué será estar en la viña? Quid hic statis? ¿Aquí, que es lugar de trabajar? ¿Aquí, donde están los buenos trabajadores echando el bofe y **sudando la gota tan gorda por ir adelante**? ¿Aquí estáis vosotros ociosos?*
>
> Fray Alonso de Cabrera, "De las consideraciones sobre todos los evangelios de la Cuaresma", a1598 (España).

Con el tiempo, la expresión prescindió del "tan" y se quedó en "sudar la gota gorda". La expresión siguió como "sudar la gota tan gorda" en el diccionario hasta 1852, donde ya se recoge tanto como "la gota tan gorda" como "la gota gorda". Durante la segunda mitad del siglo XX se recogían "la gota gorda", "tan gorda" y "tan gorda como el puño". Finalmente, desde la edición de 2001 se recoge únicamente "la gota gorda".

El primer caso de "gota gorda" aparece en el CORDE por parte de otro gran escritor:

> *Salía de su casa una buscona piramidal, **habiendo hecho sudar la gota gorda a su portada** dando paso a un inmenso contorno de faldas y tan abultada, que pudiera ir por debajo rellena de ganapanes como la tarasca: arrempujaba con el ruedo las dos aceras de una plazuela.*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "La hora de todos y la Fortuna con seso", 1635 (España).

Fue un visionario, porque no aparecen más casos de "gota gorda" en el CORDE hasta el siglo XIX.

Comment: Googleando el texto de Quevedo lo encuentro en distintos lugares como _gota tan gorda_. ¿Será que una edición de la obra corrigió esa expresión tomando las reglas del castellano actual?

Comment: @fedorqui pues es probable, no te digo que no...